# If $a,b$ are commuting normal elements of a $C^*$-algebra, then does $a$ commute with $b^*$?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

If $a,b$ in a $C^*$-algebra, such that $aa^*=a^*a,bb^*=b^*b$, and $ab=ba$.

Then do we have $ab^*=b^*a$ and $a^*b=ba^*$?

Comment: Yes, this is true, but not so trivial to prove. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem The proof I know uses basic complex analysis (Liouville's theorem).

Comment: What do you think, shin chan?  Please add your thoughts, and the source of the question, e.g.

Comment: Please explain what motivates the problem or what research you did before posting.

Answer (score 3):

This is true, and this result is known as Fuglede's theorem. Here is a proof outline:

(STEP 1) If $A$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a,b \in A$, show that the map
$$f: \mathbb{C}\to A: \lambda \mapsto e^{i\lambda b}a e^{-i\lambda b}$$
is differentiable with $f'(0) =i(ba-ab).$

(STEP 2) Let $A$ be an arbitrary $C^*$-algebra and $a\in A$ normal and $b \in A$ an element that commutes with $a$. Let $\widetilde{A}$ be the unitisation of $A$ and define
$$f: \mathbb{C}\to \widetilde{A}: \lambda \mapsto e^{i \lambda a^*}be^{-i \lambda a^*}.$$
Show that $\|f(\lambda)\| = \|b\|$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and invoke's Liouville's theorem from functional analysis to deduce that $f$ is necessarily constant (**hint**: Liouville's theorem applies only to analytic functions that take values in $\mathbb{C}$, so you will have to compose with functionals on $\widetilde{A}$ and use that functionals separate the points).

(STEP 3) Use step 2 to conclude.

Comment: Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|137.4368), which addresses answerers who regularly answer problem statement questions, like this one, which are lacking context.